# Converting command script to powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line

I have this command prompt script that I need to convert to a powershell script, but I am confused with where to even start since I am unfamiliar with powershell. To begin I think I would need to declare the variables in a different way and refer to them differently within the long command.

```
@echo On
setlocal

set base_dir=D:\Temp\peijun\LoadLegacyDocs
set java_home=D:\Programs\jre6.31
set environment=stg
set result=logs\%environment%\%1.properties

"%java_home%\bin\java" -javaagent:%base_dir%\lib\openejb-3.1.4\lib\openejb-javaagent-3.1.4.jar -classpath %base_dir%\config\%environment%;%base_dir%\lib\openejb-3.1.4\lib\*;%base_dir%\lib\jar\*;%base_dir%\lib\common_lib\*;d:\documentum\config;d:\Programs\Documentum\dctm.jar -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///%base_dir%/config/%environment%/log4j.properties com.eds.jdc.util.LoadLegacyDocs %1 %2 %3
```

EDIT:

This is what I currently have. Not much change except changing how the variables are declared and referred to in the long command line. Am I on the right track?

```
Write-Host On

$env:base_dir="D:\Temp\peijun\LoadLegacyDocs"
$env:java_home="D:\Programs\jre6.31"
$env:environment="stg"
$env:result="logs\$environment\%1.properties"

"$java_home\bin\java" -javaagent:$base_dir\lib\openejb-3.1.4\lib\openejb-javaagent-3.1.4.jar -classpath $base_dir\config\$environment;$base_dir\lib\openejb-3.1.4\lib\*;$base_dir\lib\jar\*;$base_dir\lib\common_lib\*;d:\documentum\config;d:\Programs\Documentum\dctm.jar -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///$base_dir/config/$environment/log4j.properties com.eds.jdc.util.LoadLegacyDocs %1 %2 %3
```

Comment: Hardly classifiable as a java question regardless of what the script does imo.

Comment: What are the three in-params `%1 %2 %3` supposed to be? Complete file paths? Does it always has to be three parameters?

Comment: The three in-params are two file paths and a boolean.

Comment: What does the boolean symbolize? And is it paths to directories or files?

Comment: Is the boolean a true boolean or just the text True/False?

Comment: The boolean is whether changes are saved or not and the paths are to directories. The boolean is a false boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argumentlist for java is probably right (now) in my example. Try this out...

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
    [string]$dir1,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$dir2,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [boolean]$Save
)

$Env:base_dir = 'D:\Temp\peijun\LoadLegacyDocs'
$Env:java_home = 'D:\Programs\jre6.31'
$Env:environment = 'stg'
$Env:result = "logs\$Env:environment\$dir1.properties"

& "$Env:java_home\bin\Java" "-javaagent:$Env:base_dir\lib\openejb-3.1.4\lib\openejb-javaagent-3.1.4.jar" "-classpath $Env:base_dir\config\$Env:environment;$Env:base_dir\lib\openejb-3.1.4\lib\*;$Env:base_dir\lib\jar\*;$Env:base_dir\lib\common_lib\*;d:\documentum\config;d:\Programs\Documentum\dctm.jar" "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///$Env:base_dir/config/$Env:environment/log4j.properties com.eds.jdc.util.LoadLegacyDocs $dir1 $dir2 $Save"
```

But .ps1 files can't be started "stand alone", you must use a PowerShell host (i.e. the PowerShell console) and not cmd.exe to run it.